# Bigquery with thousand plus of case statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset with around 500 million records and I have requirement to derive two columns based on sequential processing of case statemens something like

```
Select Field1,
Field2,
Case when (expression1a and expression2c and expression 3d)
     Then ‘abc’
Case when (expression1b and (expression 2f or expression 3))
     Then ‘def’
Case when (expression1x and expression 2f and expression 3)
     Then ‘ghi’
Case when (expression1 and expression 2n and expression 3)
     Then ‘nop’
....
.....
......
.....
Else ‘unp’ end as field3
From table
```

With such a large query length I am facing issue of 250k character limit as well. Is there any better way to handle this scenario on google cloud?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to solve your problem would be to create a table and populate a column where you could list all these variables. Something like:

```
SELECT field1 as tmp
FROM humongoustable
WHERE tmp IN (SELECT words from smaller_table)
```

You would do this for every variable you needed and hopefully would be able to complete the query under the limit.

Also something else you may want to look into, is creating a new column in the table based on values that you are looking for and populate them as True/False and perform filters and joins based on these new columns. These columns could be in other tables or in the same table.

Comment: "Big Query doesn't support nested queries" Are you referring to WITH clauses (CTEs)? BigQuery does support them.

Comment: Is Bigquery UDF kind approach would help in such scenario?

Comment: From the looks of it here: [Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limits) it seems that there is still a limit of your query since it states `Each inline code blob is limited to a maximum size of 32 KB.`